# Getting the grasp of Couchbase using memcached buckets

Tags: php, memcached, couchbase

The case I have is that I currently have 3 memcached instances running at 3 different servers. My application is currently at the same 3 different nodes. All the applications servers know of all the memcached servers, but if one of them goes down, I have no way of notice.
The idea is to move the memcached servers to own nodes.

I have begun to look at CouchBase as maybe an alternative of solving this, but are unsure of exactly it will work.

Will it work so that I have a CouchBase cluster, on each application node, and then connect them to the different memcached servers, and CouchBase will then monitor and know which ones is alive?

In that case, how does the application which are currently tied to the memcached instances know how to get the data if one of the memcached instances are down? Or is it CouchBase that will be the middle-man taking care of where to store it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couchbase is a very adaptive platform to use when replacing a standard memcached instance. It allows you to move a lot of fault tolerances from your application to the couchbase instances.

As you are using PHP, I recommend that you use the PHP SDK when accessing the Couchbase cluster. It can be obtained here: http://www.couchbase.com/develop/php/current

Now, the important thing to know is that the SDK for PHP is 'vbucket aware'. What this means is that when you use it to connect to the Couchbase cluster it will gather all of the information for all of the nodes from the address you put into the constructor. For example:

```
#Create the Couchbase object
$cb_obj = new Couchbase("127.0.0.1:8091", "user", "pass", "default");
```

This will create an object that you are able to run commands through that will, on it's own, be able to handle all of the failovers should a node go down, etc that is required. Each language has it's own little code processes (I generally use Python myself) but once you are familiar with them they are very effective.

The cluster can be managed through a command line interface or though a web URL by accessing `http://<nodehostname>:8091/`. This is also the URL you will access to setup the initial cluster after installing it.

I would highly recommend Couchbase as an alternative to standalone memcached.

Comment: Thanks, one question regarding the gathering of information for all the nodes. Will this mean that if I have a cluster with e.x 2 couchbase servers, that by just connecting to one of them, will make the object know about the two nodes? And if the one provided goes down, will it then try to get it from the other nodes? Just wondering what happens when the couchbase server goes down, and not just a memcached bucket is down.

Comment: So the initial communication gets the list of vbuckets, but it does checks where it updates that vbucket information. What is usually a good idea is to setup some sort of Virtual IP Interface or Proxy like nginx that lets you do a round robin load balancing on all the nodes. That way if one of the nodes go down, you can still connect and get those vbucket updates without having to make a code change to support the fail-over. Other than that aspect, yes. As soon as it talks to the initial node with the Couchbase SDK, it knows about all the other servers and distributes traffic accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

With Couchbase, you would create a single cluster, consisting of each of your three nodes.  In your application, you create an instance of the PHP(?) Couchbase client and give it the URI to at least one of the nodes.  The client will learn about the topology of the cluster from any of these nodes.

The client maintains a streaming connection to the cluster and will be notified of any changes in topology.  If a node goes down, the client will react accordingly.

You can setup auto-failover and notifications to alert you to auto-failover events.